# How to read text from a txt file?

Tags: c++

Hey In txt file i have 2 columns an 15 rows. In first column there are number of taken seat and second column there are number of free seat. And my question is - how to get date only from second column and add every columns. I,m begginer so will gratefull if someone help me.

Comment: There's no way to read *only* some columns from a file. You have to read the whole file, but you can *ignore* some columns.

Comment: Ok, but how can i ignore first column ?

Comment: Read that column into a variable, and never use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply ignore the column that you don't care about. e.g.

```
std::ifstream ifs {"somefile"};
std::vector<int> free_seats;
int taken, free;
ifs >> taken >> free;  // read the first line
free_seats.push_back(free);  // and simply never use 'taken'
```